# Discord Bot to start Minecraft Server

Tags: java, server, discord, bots, minecraft

How do I program a Discord bot to start a Minecraft server? The only up-to-date tutorial to program a Discord bot is for python, but it seems like you need JavaScript code to write something similar (for example this Github code - but how do i implement it in a bot? https://gist.github.com/simonmeusel/1de7166288b12c04518c59158a85f5ef). Can anyone recommend an up-to-date tutorial and tell me how to implement the code from Github so that I can start the Minecraft Server via writing a command in a Discord channel?

The Minecraft server I would like to start is hosted by a third party website.

I hope this was enough info.

Edit: changed Java to JavaScript

Comment: Do you know the difference between Java and JavaScript?

Comment: Oh, yes I do :facepalm: I just noticed it was in JavaScript. But how would I implement the code into my bot?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i found it out myself. I found a good tutorial on YouTube how to program your bot in .js, I was able to add the code there. Here is the vid:
https://youtu.be/7rU_KyudGBY

Answer (score 0):

I added a command like this to my discord.js bot,
here is the code, all it does is execute the batch file that runs the minecraft server.

`client.on('message', message => {`

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

if(command === 'runmc'){
    const {exec} = require('child_process');
    console.log('Starting MC server');
    message.channel.send('Starting Minecraft Server...');
    exec('start RUNMC.bat')
    return;                         
};
```